# How would I check if a filtered request returns an empty array?

Tags: python, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I started Javascript around a year and a half ago but I started Python around a week ago so I'm still a beginner at this. So I'm trying to figure out if a user is already stored into the users table and if they aren't then it will add them to it and if they are then it skips.

```
import rethinkdb as r


r.db('bot').table('users').filter(r.row["id"] == "253544423110082589").run()
```

this code should return

```
<rethinkdb.net.DefaultCursor object at 0x03DAAE10> (done streaming):
[
]
```

So how exactly would I check if its empty?

I tried something like

```
if not r.db('bot').table('users').filter(r.row["id"] == "253544423110082589").run():
    # add user to table
else:
    continue
```

but it continues even when the user isn't in the table. So please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can actually get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/python/is_empty/) use the `is_empty` function:

```
r.db('bot').table('users').filter(r.row["id"] == "253544423110082589").is_empty().run(conn)
```

You could also use [`count`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/count/)

```
r.db('bot').table('users').filter(r.row["id"] == "253544423110082589").count().run(conn)
```

Comment: For some reason is_empty didn't work but using count did work so thanks for the help!!

Comment: no problem. please accept and upvote my answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but you may be able to check the length of the table.

It might look something like this:

```
if len(table) == 0:
    # add user to table
else:
    continue
```